# Find and update child of child in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let's take an exemple :

```
listCollection = {
    id_list:"111",
    child_list:[{
        id_list:"222",
        child_list:[{
            id_list:"333",
            child_list:[{
                // and it can be more
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

As you see, it is always the same object inside the same object. The initial object is :

```
var list = {
    id_list: "string",
    child_list:[]
};
```

**Using mongoDB, I would like to Find, Update or Push list anywhere I want inside the collection, only by knowing the id_list.**
This is the most far I was :

```
db.collection("listCollection").findOneAndUpdate({
    "child_list.id_list": "listId"
}, {
    "$push": {
        "child_list.$.child_list": newList
    }
}, function(err, success) {
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err); 
    } else { 
        console.log(success); 
    }
})
```

It works fine for the first level of child, but not more.
I am pretty new to Node JS + mongoDB, can you help me a little bit with this ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found my way through this. Not a really beautiful one, but a working one.

Let's retake my exemple :

```
listCollection = {
    child_list:[{
        child_list:[{
            child_list:[

            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to add a new child_list at the end of the hierarchy. At the end, I want my collection to look like that :

```
listCollection = {
    child_list:[{
        child_list:[{
            child_list:[{
                child_list:[

                ]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Yeah, it is kind of a dumb exemple but it is a simple one :)
So here is the object I want to insert :

```
var theNewChildList= {
    child_list:[] 
};
```

Then, I will need a kind of "route" of where I want to put theNewChildList.
Here, I want to push it at listCollection.child_list[0].child_list[0].child_list

So I just use that string :

```
var myRoute = "child_list.0.child_list.0.child_list";
```

Then, I prepare your mongoDB query like that :

```
var query = {};
query[myRoute] = theNewChildList;
```

and finally, I do the query :

```
db.collection("myCollectionOfList").findOneAndUpdate(
    {}, // or any condition to find listCollection
    {"$push": query},

    function(err, success) {
    if (err) { 
        console.log(err); 
    } else { 
        console.log(success); 
    }
})
```

And it works.
Note that you have many ways to prepare the var myRoute dynamically.

I you have other ideas, please share :)